# API Usage in Android Studio -- Olympics API

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-studio

I have been trying to create an app in Android Studio that utilizes the Olympics API, but have been having a lot of trouble actually accessing the data.

Within Android Studio, I understand how to use a library called Ion to open up a url, and then store the data from that url in a JSON object. When trying to access the data from the Olympics API, however, I keep just accessing a template-looking piece of code. Their documentation is located here: http://docs.olympicsapi.apiary.io/#reference/olympics/events-collection/list-all-events?console=1

The template-looking piece of code is located [here (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d8Sw.png)

and the actual JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "id":       Event_ID_as_int,
    "name":     "Event Name",
    "sport":    "Sport Name",
    "olympics": [
                    {
                        "id":       "Olympic_ID",
                        "year":     "Year",
                        "season":   "Season type (Summer/Winter)"
                    }
                ]
}
```

What am I missing here? I understand that the url that leads here contains "mock" in it and that this is likely a sample link, but how can I access the actual data? I have looked through their github repository (located on the left of the documentation page) and found the actual data located within the db folder and some extra coding examples written in Python; I just don't know how to simply ask for the results of a specific event within a specific year and get accurate data from it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you may want to look into using Retrofit. It will make your life a LOT easier when working with rest api's: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: It appears you've found a class project for the framework of a website which can provide sports data. If you want to use it, you'll have to host the website yourself.

Comment: Any update...? Also looking for an answer